# Error in my data base but I don't see whats wrong

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a WordPress database into phpMyAdmin but for some reason, I get this error. I was wondering if anyone could help me.

[image]

Comment: Copy & paste the information in readable format in order to help search engines

Answer (score 0):

If your are using a version > 5.1 You should use  engine INNODB instead of TYPE = InnoDB.

```
 ENGINE = Innodb AUTO_INCREMENT = 80;
```

TYPE was removed in 5.1.

Comment: So everywhere it says that I should change it?

Comment: if you are using a db version > 5.1  yes .. TYPE is Removed

Comment: But now i get this - Error
SQL query:

--
-- Dumping data for table `wp_commentmeta`
--
INSERT INTO  `wp_commentmeta` (  `meta_id` ,  `comment_id` ,  `meta_key` ,  `meta_value` ) 
VALUES ( 39, 46,  'is_customer_note',  '1' ) ;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1062 - Duplicate entry '39' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: I don't understand what i have to do?

Comment: i was missign the = sign before 80  in my answer  .. i have added  now ...so you  should use ENGINE = Innodb AUTO_INCREMENT = 80; and be sure you have not previuos value that interfer with your actual action   .. eg drop the table an recreate

Comment: I have done that - ENGINE = InnoDB  AUTO_INCREMENT = 80 ; - and it still comes up with that error also i have checked for previous action

Comment: this mean that error related  to the table creation is solved (your original quest)  .. but you have some other query (that we can't view)  that run after the table creation  (insert)  this query  insert  value for duplicated  pk  ..   But  this is a new question for this you should post a specific question  ... SO is not a tutorial for install  wp .. SO  is a question answer site  and for your question  i and others person have found  the reason and the solution  .. so  ..

Answer (score 0):

Use ENGINE = Innodb instead of TYPE = InnoDB. TYPE was removed in 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this format:

```
CREATE TABLE `aud_admission2017`.`wp_commentmeta`(  
  `meta_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `meta_key` VARCHAR(255),
  `meta_value` LONGTEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  INDEX (`comment_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
AUTO_INCREMENT=80;
```

Comment: This didnt work - #1142 - CREATE command denied to user 'loydul159'@'10.1.4.11' for table 'wp_commentmeta' 
 - That was the error

Comment: Everywhere it says TYPE Should I change it to engine?